# Reference a cmsplugin from another cmsplugin

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm searching for a flexible way to reference one cmsplugin from another cmsplugin in order to allow the user to create links between them.

This must be a very common problem, so there should be a standard solution. But I cannot find it.

My current idea is to add a field to the model of my cmsplugin that is (in my case) a `ManyToManyField` pointing to something like `CMSPluginBase`. Then one has to set the option `limit_choices_to` and render the form in a way that the choices are displayed in a human readable way. But I want to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I don't think this is as common as you think. I haven't seen anything that does this so your solution is a good way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the `title` field as unique identifiert of my `CMSPlugin` objects. When looking for related objects, I first take their titles, and then perform a query that collects all objects with the correct title and language that are published. Surely, this is not a nice solution.

There is a standard way to deal with relations in `CMSPlugin` models. One should define a `copy_related` method, as explained [here](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.3/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html#handling-relations). But this solution did not relaiably work for me when the relationships pointed to another `CMSPlugin`. This is due to the mechanism how draft pages are turned into published pages.